# Assigning StringBuilder output to String Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, stringbuilder

I went through several examples on the site & all of them had assigning the StringBuilder output to a String variable. I want to assign the value into an array. Whan I used the `char names[]= s1.toString().toCharArray();` worked. But now `String names[]= s1.toString();` dosen't work. Following is my code,

```
public static String[] Assign(String fn1, String ln1, String fn2, String ln2)               //Functions to assign names into arrays//
{       
    String fname1[]= fn1.split("(?!^)");                                //Storing the user's 1st name in an array//
    String lname1[]= ln1.split("(?!^)");                                //Storing the user's last name in an array//

    String fname2[]= fn2.split("(?!^)");                                //Storing the friend's 1st name in an array//
    String lname2[]= ln2.split("(?!^)");                                //Storing the friend's last name in an array//

    String and[]= {"a","n","d"};                                    //Array for the and part//

    StringBuilder s1= new StringBuilder(100);  
    s1.append(fname1);
    s1.append(lname1);
    s1.append(and);
    s1.append(fname2);
    s1.append(lname2);                                      //Breaking down the arrays//

    String names[] = s1.toString();                                     //Store the arrays into 1 array//

    return names;                                           //Returning the array//

}
```

Comment: _into an array_ or _to an array_? The latter won't work. A `String` is not a `String[]`.

Comment: You can put s1 as an element of String array `names` but you want to split it up as each character is a different index of the `names` array?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can you please show me where I went wrong. I didn't get you very well. I'm still a beginner.

Comment: @ZeldaZach Yeah

Comment: What are you expecting to be the content of `names`?

Comment: @AndréStannek The characters of the arrays fname1, lname1, etc. should be saved into individual array cells of names array

Comment: Can someone please explain why my post is downvoted so I can fix the errors.

Answer (score -1):

Based on what was asked, how to put a String into a `String[]` as individual characters in each index (where it probably should be a `char[]`, which is how I will give my example), we can take a string and insert it as such:

```
char names[] = new char[s1.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
{
    names[i] = s1.charAt(i);
}
```

That should help solve the issue.

If needed to be a `String[]` for some reason...

```
String names[] = new String[s1.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
{
    names[i] = Character.toString(s1.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter, any reason? Would love to learn what's wrong with the answer

Comment: @ZeldaZach I'm not the downvoter but you answered the question at a point where it was, imho, unclear what OP was asking. You seemed to be guessing a question. As I said I didn't downvote but I flaged as "Not an answer". I've withdrawn that flag now because it turned out you guessed correctly :-)